# Is there a rating scale in psychology that is related to happiness?

Tags: emotion, clinical-psychology, positive-psychology

There are many rating scales used in psychiatry to rate the severity of disorders. Thus, the extensive depression scales. What about the opposite, happiness scales? If 0 denotes excessive depressive symptoms and 100 denotes absence of these symptoms, does a scale exist that say goes from 100 (absence of depressive symptoms) to 200 (hyperthymia, euphoria)?

Comment: I do not know about such scales, so sorry for that. Yet, I would like to inform you that it is hard to talk about the 'opposite' of depression, since this is a rather heterogeneous disorder with many facets. Additionally, in the sense of positive vs negative emotions, it should be stated that these constructs aren't opposites of one another, but rather independent constructs (cfr. Watson, Clark, & Carey. (1988). Positive and negative affectivity and their relation to anxiety and depressive disorders. Journal of abnormal psychology, 97(3), 346-354.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of scales that are used to measure happiness.

- One widely used measure is the [PANAS](http://booksite.elsevier.com/9780123745170/Chapter%203/Chapter_3_Worksheet_3.1.pdf), the "Positive and Negative Affect Schedule" (Watson, Clark, & Tellegen, 1988).
- Lyubomirsky and Lepper (1999) have developed the [Subjective Happiness Scale](http://sonjalyubomirsky.com/subjective-happiness-scale-shs/),
- there is the [satisfaction with life scale](http://internal.psychology.illinois.edu/~ediener/SWLS.html) (Diener et al. 1985),
- and the [Oxford Happiness Scale](http://happiness-survey.com/survey/) (Hills and Argyle, 2002)

I don't think these scales measure a kind of excessive euphoria or other maladaptive states that you may or may not have in mind, given that you allude to depression. If yes, you may want to look into the diagnosis of bipolar disorder, or questionnaires about drug consumption. This would not be about happiness per se though.

**References**

Diener, E., Emmons, R. A., Larsen, R. J., & Griffin, S. (1985). The Satisfaction with Life Scale. Journal of Personality Assessment, 49, 71-75.

Hills, P., & Argyle, M. (2002). The Oxford Happiness Questionnaire: a compact scale for the measurement of psychological well-being. Personality and Individual Differences, 33(7), 1073–1082. http://doi.org/10.1016/S0191-8869(01)00213-6

Lyubomirsky, S., & Lepper, H. (1999). A measure of subjective happiness: Preliminary reliability and construct validation. Social Indicators Research, 46, 137-155

Watson, D., Clark, L. A. & Tellegen, A. (1988). Development and validation of brief measures of positive and negative affect: The PANAS Scales. Journal of Personality and Social Psychology, 54, 1063–1070.